# How do you concatenate two dataframes but only take values from one if there is a conflict?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

1:

```
     col1 col2

a    a1    a2
b    b1    b2
```

1:

```
     col1 col2

b    b3    b4
c    c1    c2
```

I want to concatenate them but for the first to take precedence when the index is the same. So I want to get:

```
     col1 col2
a    a1    a2
b    b1    b2
c    c1    c2
```

I can't find a simple(ish) way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with select first duplicates row by indices:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
print (df)
  col1 col2
a   a1   a2
b   b1   b2
c   c1   c2
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for answering. Does this always keep the values from the first dataframe?

Comment: Yes, if duplicates in indices.

Comment: this doesn't appear to have worked on my dataset. perhaps something else is going wrong

Comment: It seems to not to have remove the duplicate indices

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: Hey so it appears that the problem is that one index was saved as a string and the other as integers. Thanks very much anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2']], index=['a', 'b'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['b3', 'b4'], ['c1', 'c2']], index=['b', 'c'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df1.combine_first(df2)

#   col1 col2
# a   a1   a2
# b   b1   b2
# c   c1   c2
```

Comment: thanks for answering but this doesn't seem to have worked either on my actual dataset. I still have the equivalent to both 'b' rows. I guess something else is definitely going wrong

Comment: Hey so it appears that the problem is that one index was saved as a string and the other as integers. Thanks very much anyway!